# What is the distance between $[1,2)$ and $(2,4]$?

Tags: metric-spaces

I know that $d(A,B)>0$ if two sets do not intersect. However what is the distance if two sets are very close two each other like $[1,2)$ and $(2,4]$?

Comment: How do you define the distance between two sets of real numbers?

Comment: _I know that $d(A,B) > 0$ if two sets do not intersect_ —are you sure?  What in the definition of distance of sets says this?

Comment: @MatthewLeingang, this is the definition I am using $$\operatorname{dist}(A,B)=\inf\{d(a,b):a \in A,b \in B\}$$
.

Comment: $a_n=2-1/n,b_n=2+1/n,d(b_n,a_n)=2/n\to0$

Comment: OK, good.  Are $A$ and $B$ subsets of $\mathbb{R}$?

Comment: How do you “know” the first sentence?

Comment: @MatthewLeingang, Yes.

Comment: So your example just show you what you know is incorrect.

Comment: Apply the definition to the two sets you suggested.  If $A = [1,2)$ and $B = (2,4]$, what is $d(A,B)$?

Comment: Your statement is true if $A$ and $B$ are both compact sets.

Comment: @MatthewLeingang, the definition suggests to me that $d(A,B)>0$

Comment: No.  The infimum of a set of positive numbers can be zero.  For instance the set $\{\frac{1}{n}~:~n\in\Bbb N\} = \{\frac{1}{1},\frac{1}{2},\frac{1}{3},\frac{1}{4},\dots\}$ has infimum equal to zero.

Comment: You should be able to convince yourself that $[1,2)$ and $(2,3]$ are closer together than $\frac{1}{2}$.  They are closer together than $\frac{1}{100}$.  They are closer together than even $\frac{1}{10000000000000000}$ and so on.... they are closer together than any strictly positive number you pick.  And so...

Comment: @JMoravitz, oh I get it now, so $d(A,B)=0$.

Comment: Yes, and this is shown using the very definition you cited involving the infimum and citing specific sequences of elements of $A$ and $B$ whose limit of distances between them approaches zero such as in ShubhamJohri's comment above, showing that the infimum of the set of distances is also zero.

Comment: For future reference, the distance between $[a,b]$ and $[c,d]$ with $a<b\leq c< d$ regardless whether or not we replace any of the square brackets with parentheses instead will always be $c-b$.  In this case $d([1,2),(2,3])=2-2=0$ while $d([1,2],(7,9))=7-2=5$ and so on.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I thought I would summarize the comments so that the question can have an answer.

The definition of distance between subsets of a metric space is: $$d(A,B) = \inf \{d(a,b) \mid a \in A,\ b \in B\}$$
If $A = [1,2)$ and $B = (2,4]$, both as subsets of $\mathbb{R}$ with its usual metric $d(a,b) = |a-b|$, what is $d(A,B)$?

You are correct that if sets $E$ and $F$ have a common point $x$, then $d(E,F) = 0$.  Because you can count $x$ as both a point in $E$ and in $F$, and $d(x,x) =0$.    But the converse—that $E \cap F = \emptyset \implies d(E,F) > 0$ is not true.

Why would the definition (falsely) “suggest” that the distance between disjoint sets is positive?  Because $d(a,b) > 0$ whenever $a \neq b$.  But as JMoravitz points out, *the infimum of a set of positive numbers need not be a positive number*.  And Shubham Johri ever-so-succinctly provides an explicit pair of sequences $a_n \in A$, $b_n \in B$, such that $d(a_n,b_n) > 0$ for all $n$, but $\lim_{n \to\infty} d(a_n,b_n) = 0$.  This means that $d(A,B) = 0$.

This illustrates an important property of the real numbers—they are *dense* in the sense for any $x,y \in \mathbb{R}$ with $x < y$ there exists $z$ such that $x < z < y$.  Such is not the case for integers, and indeed, for subsets of $\mathbb{Z}$, $d(A,B) =0 \iff A \cap B \neq \emptyset$.